# Running time of nested loops (Big O)

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, big-o

What is the running time of this algorithm:

```
for i=1 to n^2
    for j=1 to i
        // some constant time operation
```

I want to say O(n^4) but I can't be certain. How do you figure this out?

Comment: It is obviously `O(n^4)`. It's also (not so obviously) `Θ(n^4)`.

Comment: Never mind, I calculated wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

n^4 is correct.  The inner loop takes an average of (n^2)/2 time to run, because `i` goes up to n^2 linearly, and it is run (n^2) times.

Comment: Oh that's the missing link: the average time of the inner loop is (n^2)/2. Thanks, that makes sense. It also confirms the numbers that I crunched.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, it is `N^4`.

Do the substitution `M = N^2`. Now your loops change to this:

```
for i in 0..M
    for j in 0..i
```

This is your familiar `O(M^2)`, hence the result is `O((N^2)^2) = O(N^4)` after the reverse substitution.

Answer (score 2):

The constant time operation is run:

```
  1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n^2        (n^2 adders)
```

times which is less than:

```
  n^2 + n^2 + ... + n^2        (n^2 adders)
= n^2 * n^2
= n^4
```

So, it's obviously `O(n^4)`

---

To prove it's `Θ(n^4)`, you can use a liitle math:

```
   1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n^2   
 = n^2 * (n^2 + 1) / 2
 = n^4 / 2 + n^2 / 2
>= n^4 / 2
```

Comment: That makes sense for proving it is O(n^4) but I don't think that proves it is the tightest upper bound.

Comment: Well when analyzing algorithms, it doesn't seem very useful to give an upper bound if it isn't the tightest upper bound. For example, the algorithm is also O(n^5) and O(n!) but that doesn't help to determine the run time.

Comment: That's what `O` notation is. An upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

With nested loops the Big Oh run time multiplicative.  So Big Oh of the outer loop (N^2) is multiplied by the Big Oh of the inner (N^2).  Therefore the Big Oh is (N^2 * N^2) and if you remember how to add exponents of a similar base you get N^(2+2) or N^4.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma Notation, you end up getting the order of growth methodically:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
n^5 = outer * inner
outer = n^2
inner = n^2 + n^2-1 + n^2-2 +...1
```

Comment: In your notation: `inner = 1+1+...+1`